# Как передать переменную в render?

Tags: node.js

Ребят, помогите разобраться, я с node js совсем недавно, да и с js тоже. Программировал на PHP, но тут совсем другое и все въехать не могу в работу node js.

На странице нужно сделать две выборки, вывести разделы (категории) и сами записи из mongodb

Делаю так

```
exports.get = function(req, res, next) {

// Выборка с коллекции catalogs
Catalog.get(function(err, catalog) {
    if(err) return next(err);

    //console.log(catalog) // массив записей

    var catalog = catalog;
});

// Выборка с коллекции news
News.get(function(err, post) {
    if(err) return next(err);

    //console.log(post) // массив записей

    var post = post;
});

res.render('home', {
    catalogs: catalog,
    posts: post
});

};
```

> ReferenceError: catalogs is not
> defined ReferenceError: posts is not
> defined

Как передать содержимое в render?

Comment: Въезжать долго придется. Легче нирвану достигнуть, чем эту асинхронность понять сразу. Мне очень помогли скринкасты Ильи Кантора (http://learn.javascript.ru/nodejs-screencast).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В javascript используется функциональная область видимости (возможно некорректно назвал, но пофиг))) ). То есть, переменная объявленная в функции в ней и останется и "снаружи" ее не увидеть. Именно поэтому

```
ReferenceError: catalogs is not defined ReferenceError: posts is not defined
```

Почему именно на переменные catalogs и posts ругается непонятно. Должно было на catalog и post выругаться. Покажите весь стек из консоли. Для решения вашей задачи подойдет [эта функция из модуля async](https://github.com/caolan/async#parallel). Реализация:

```
exports.get = function (req, res, next) {
    async.parallel([
        Catalog.get,
        News.get
    ], function (err, result) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        res.render('home', {
            catalogs: result.catalog,
            posts: result.post
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: спс. Пока конечно не понятно все таки как это работает и что такое Catalog.get )))
Почитаю про async, может разберусь =)

Comment: Catalog.get(function(){}) вызывает метод get объекта Catalog с параметром function(){...}. Вам не с async-ом разбираться надо сначала, а с базовым javascript и асинхронностью в node.js. Хотя, если стоит одноразовая задача, то и так сойдет.

Comment: нет, это не одноразовая задача, буду разбираться, просто уже много прочел, но все это сразу не переварить, к тому же логика PHP очень сильно мешает в этом разобраться как я понял. Еще раз спс )

Comment: ту ошибка не в видимости переменных (например, если бы они были объявлены глобально, то тоже ничего бы не вышло), а в асинхронности.  
кроме того, правильный синтаксис будет:

    async.parallel({
        catalog: Catalog.get,
        post: News.get
      }, function (err, result) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        res.render('home', {
            catalogs: result.catalog,
            posts: result.post
        });
    });

Comment: да я с этим разобрался, почитал про async.parallel. Уже получилось сделать задуманное. Оказалось все просто, но нужно будет еще почитать про все это и про другие методы тоже.

Comment: Блин, точно. Извините, вместо объекта массив написал.